# After sending on a socket, connection has been closed

Tags: c#, sockets, network-programming, tcplistener

I am using the example at [Microsoft: asynchronous-server-socket-example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-server-socket-example).
The problem is, when I send back the data to the client the data arrives to the client; but when I try again from the client to send data to the server listener then it seems the connection has been closed, because nothing will arrive on the server socket.

In my application I should run an async tcp server that is listening and sometimes for certain messages i have to send back some data on the connection established for the port of that socket.

Comment: did you see ```handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);  handler.Close(); ``` in sendcallback?

Comment: yes, I cut them off. I see that, after calling `EndSend`, if I send more data from the client then the server won't intercept it.. it is still executing `allDone.WaitOne()`;

Comment: most likely you need to reschedule receive operation in readcallback unconditionaly ```handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);``` , i.e. outside of ```if```

Comment: YES, I AM BLIND -.-'